# SVG повторяющийся фон с полным перекрытием

Tags: css, svg, background

Делаю 404 страницу по макету дизайнера. Столкнулся с проблемой что если фон задается через повторяющийся SVG элемент, то появляться промежутки между элементами. Приведу пример

```css
body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #FFF;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #17BDFE, #DDFF0B, #FE8E04, #E01D00);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.decor_404 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0' y='0' viewBox='0 0 76 56' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0v56h76V0H0zm36.3 42.3h-5.5v9.4h-9.3v-9.4H1.4v-7.9c1.8-2 3.6-4.2 5.5-6.5 1.9-2.4 3.7-4.8 5.5-7.3 1.8-2.5 3.4-5 5-7.6 1.5-2.5 2.8-5 3.9-7.3h9.4v29h5.5v7.6zm33 4c-2.9 4.2-7.1 6.2-12.6 6.2-11 0-16.4-7.7-16.4-23.1 0-8 1.5-14.1 4.4-18.3 3-4.2 7.3-6.3 12.9-6.3 10.7 0 16.1 7.8 16.1 23.5 0 7.9-1.5 13.8-4.4 18z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M57.1 12.6c-4.4 0-6.6 5.5-6.6 16.5 0 10.4 2.2 15.6 6.5 15.6 4.2 0 6.3-5.4 6.3-16.1 0-10.6-2-16-6.2-16zM16.3 27c-1 1.4-1.9 2.7-2.9 4-1 1.3-1.9 2.5-2.9 3.6h11v-16c-.7 1.4-1.6 2.8-2.4 4.2-.9 1.4-1.8 2.8-2.8 4.2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), radial-gradient(circle, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0.065) 0%, rgba(5, 6, 16, 0.65) 100%);
  background-repeat: repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 -10vh, 50% 50%;
  background-size: 30vh, 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0) 0%, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0.51) 7.29%, #050612 50.52%, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0.51) 90.1%, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0) 100%);
  z-index: 4;
}

.main__title {
  margin: 0 auto 30px;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 46px;
}

.main__text {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 760px;
  font-size: 19px;
  color: #D1D1D1;
}

.main__return-link {
  margin: 58px auto 0;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 168px;
  height: 56px;
  line-height: 56px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #67DC00, #4DA600);
  box-shadow: 0 -4px 18px rgba(23, 49, 0, .8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main__return-link:hover,
.main__return-link:focus {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #4DA600, #67DC00);
}

 ::selection {
  background: #65D900;
}

 ::-moz-selection {
  background: #65D900;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main__title {
    margin: auto 15px;
    font-size: 29px;
  }
  .main__text {
    max-width: 330px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .main__return-link {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="decor_404"></div>
<main class="main">

  <h1 class="main__title">Вы попали не туда</h1>

  <p class="main__text">Извините, возможно эта страница была удалена, либо допущена ошибка в адресе.<br/> Перейдите на главную страницу.</p>
  <a href="/" class="main__return-link">на главную</a>
</main>
```

На малых размерах окна браузера не так явно видно, а вот на больших видно
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста из-за чего это может происходить, и можно ли от этого избавиться ?

Comment: Вообще для бесшовной раскладки можно использовать pattern в svg, тогда не должно быть таких проблем

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-svg-patterns-as-backgrounds--cms-31507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В этом случае можно пойти несколькими путями:

1.Использовать элемент `<pattern>` для `<svg>`

2.Просто убрать черный фон из svg, если это возможно

3.Использовать атрибут `preserveAspectRatio` со значением `'none'`:

```
background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' x='0' y='0' preserveAspectRatio='none' viewBox='0 0 76 56' xml:space='preserve'%3E%3Cpath d='M0 0v56h76V0H0zm36.3 42.3h-5.5v9.4h-9.3v-9.4H1.4v-7.9c1.8-2 3.6-4.2 5.5-6.5 1.9-2.4 3.7-4.8 5.5-7.3 1.8-2.5 3.4-5 5-7.6 1.5-2.5 2.8-5 3.9-7.3h9.4v29h5.5v7.6zm33 4c-2.9 4.2-7.1 6.2-12.6 6.2-11 0-16.4-7.7-16.4-23.1 0-8 1.5-14.1 4.4-18.3 3-4.2 7.3-6.3 12.9-6.3 10.7 0 16.1 7.8 16.1 23.5 0 7.9-1.5 13.8-4.4 18z'/%3E%3Cpath d='M57.1 12.6c-4.4 0-6.6 5.5-6.6 16.5 0 10.4 2.2 15.6 6.5 15.6 4.2 0 6.3-5.4 6.3-16.1 0-10.6-2-16-6.2-16zM16.3 27c-1 1.4-1.9 2.7-2.9 4-1 1.3-1.9 2.5-2.9 3.6h11v-16c-.7 1.4-1.6 2.8-2.4 4.2-.9 1.4-1.8 2.8-2.8 4.2z'/%3E%3C/svg%3E"), radial-gradient(circle, rgba(5, 6, 18, 0.065) 0%, rgba(5, 6, 16, 0.65) 100%);
```

Вроде это частично решает проблему, швы на стыках могут быть заметны только при изменении размеров окна браузера.

Еще это может лучше работать с абсолютными значениями в `px`.

Comment: голосую за второй вариант

Comment: Спасибо, метод с pattern  помог.  А ещё вопрос, возможно ли до svg тега pattern достучаться через CSS ? Я просто попробовал  .decor_404 svg pattern{
            width:304px;
            height:224px;
        } и думал, что смогу потом менять размеры картинки паттерна для мобильных устройств через медиавыражения, но не работает

Comment: @BlackStar1991 свойства  width  и height тут не помогут,до pattern не достучаться через css, как вариант применять transform: scale() к <path> , но тогда придеться пересчитывать значения width и height для <pattern> в через calc(), ну или как то ещё решить на JS, думаю без него никак

Comment: Еще можно весь код с <pattern>, как вы делали , поместить в background-image: url(), но думаю это так себе

Comment: И еще, есть один смешной вариант: использовать <use> для каждого отдельного блока <svg>, не знаю решит ли это проблему с бесшовным фоном, но адаптивно будет точно

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Ну а вообще, в этом случае, менее накладно убрать фон из svg и делать все так как вы делали с background, у вас же не какой-то повторяющийся бесшовный узор, у вас есть поля там

Comment: Меня вариант с <pattern> устроил на 90% делал как в уроке Adi Purdila  . Единственный минус, что пока не понятно,можно ли менять размеры самого повторяющегося элемента, скажем для отображений на мобильном меньших элементов.  Метод через background-image с присваиванием значения preserveAspectRatio ="none" немного искажает картинку паттерна (это заметно, ну и CSS раздувает если оно там большое) *интересное наблюдение в Chrome Canary данного бага не возникает

Comment: @BlackStar1991 Задайте вопрос на счет изменения размеров, может кто расскажет, самому интересно